# Show top 3 random posts on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom page where there are 10 posts showing right now, what i need to show first 3 random then next 4-7 again random and 8-10 again random
Is their any way i can manage in the while loop

```
<?php
$count = 1;
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
echo the_title();
$count++;
endwhile;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: I googled your title and literally 3 million hits came up.

Comment: whats that means? :)

Comment: Let me get this clear. You have 10 posts, you want to display all of them. What is random about it? Don't you mean that you want the order to be random?

Comment: I have 10 posts and its showing fine.. what i need to shuffle/random post 1-3, 4-7 and then 8-10 every time when user refresh the page

Comment: i dont know its possible to break loop and then shuffle something like between 1-3 break and shuffle then same as others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should get you close to what you want.
Put your posts into an array first:

```
$posts = array();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    array_push($posts, $post);
}
```

Then sort that array. I'll demonstrate with 0-9:

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$first = array_slice($array, 0, 3);
$second = array_slice($array, 3, 4);
$third = array_slice($array, 7, 3);
shuffle($first);
shuffle($second);
shuffle($third);
$newarray = array_merge($first, $second, $third);
print join(", ", $array) . "\n" . join(", ", $newarray) . "\n";
```

Which will lead to a random-ish sorting of the array while keeping "blocks" (top, middle, bottom) in the same order:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 2, 0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 7, 9

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7
```

Putting it all together:

```
$posts = array();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    array_push($posts, $post);
}

$first = array_slice($posts, 0, 3);
$second = array_slice($posts, 3, 4);
$third = array_slice($posts, 7, 3);
shuffle($first);
shuffle($second);
shuffle($third);
$newposts = array_merge($first, $second, $third);
foreach($newposts as $mypost) {
    print $mypost->post_title . "<br />\n";
}
```

note that I erroneously had written `push $posts, $post;` instead of `array_push($posts, $post);`, I have written a lot of Perl lately, and it shows.

Comment: Thankd Janh2, this all code i put in the while loop?

Comment: i am getting this output
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
3, 2, 4, 8, 7, 5, 10, 6, 9, 10, 9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
4, 3, 2, 8, 5, 9, 10, 6, 7, 10, 9

Comment: no, the $array was just a demonstration, you should use an array with your posts in it, like $posts above, so the shuffle-block comes after the loop.
After shuffling, do something like `foreach($posts as $post) { echo $post->post_title() ; }`

Comment: Can you please edit the code for me :( i am bit confuse now

Comment: Thanks mate its working you are star :)

The only thing i am struggling how to show link function in foreach loop, i have developed a function and call in in a while loop. but now its in foreach loop with post object .. dont know how to call.

<?php echo aflink($id); ?>

Thanks again

Comment: $id is probably the ID of the post in question? You should be able to use `aflink($mypost->ID)`

Comment: Hi Janh2,

Sorry to bother you again :(.

I am trying to shuffle only $first which is shuffling fine but other 7 post title is not showing without shuffle 

Thanks

Comment: Also i dont understand array_slice like (0,3)(3,4)(7,3)

Thanks

Comment: So you've only left out the two lines with  `shuffle($second);
shuffle($third);`? the array_slice just splits the 10-elements result list up into three smaller arrays of 3, 4 and 3 elements, which can than be sorted individually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Janh2,

Got it :)  but still don't understand the array slice :( 

so what is 0,3,7 in every array what if i want shuffle 1,2,3 and 4,5,6,7,8,9 ? then the array should be different?

Comment: The first number is always "which position do I start at" and the second is "how many elements do you want?", so for your two arrays, you use `$first = array_slice($posts, 0, 3)` and `$second = array_slice($posts, 3, 6);`, see also http://php.net/array_slice

Comment: Thanks Janh2,
I really appreciated :